# button click crashes

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have below code in a IBAction linked to a UIButton to change the background image on Button Click.

```
    UIImage *imageGreen=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgGreen.png"];
 [clickButton setBackgroundImage:imageGreen forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [imageGreen release];
```

after clicking the button three times it crashes the app in iPhone Simulator 4.0. I am alreading releasing the imageGreen object, what else can i do to prevent this.

Comment: Please be helpful and tag the language and environment!

Answer (score 0):

No, you **should not** release `imageGreen`.

This variable is received with a convenient method, thus will autorelease itself. Calling `-release` will cause double-release error and crash the program.

Please read the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Comment: thanks kenny, i removed the release statement and it works just fine now.